# Does roslaunch support topic remapping from command line?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

The [roslaunch page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap) says that we can remap topic by simply adding this line to launch file.

```
<remap from="chatter" to="hello"/>
```

I want to ask if we can do the same thing in command line?

```
roslaunch <package name> <launch file name> chatter:=hello
```

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55461/does-roslaunch-support-topic-remapping-from-command-line?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, if roslaunch supports that - just try it.

If it doesn't, you can use args for that:

```
<arg name="from_topic" />
<remap from="from_topic" to="$(arg from_topic)"/>
```

Command line syntax should stay the same.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
Defining an **arg** is probably the best solution available.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-02-18**:
Thanks~
I tried but it doesn't work,  so I want to make sure if it was my problem or roslaunch doesn't support this function.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-02-18**:
I don't understand "Command line syntax should stay the same.". What does command line syntax look like?
Isn't it `roslaunch [package name] [launch file name] chatter:=hello`?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
That would be the syntax. But, in Christian's arg example: substitute "chatter" for "from_topic". His answer was more generic.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-19**:
I meant that the command line remapping looks exactly the same as when remapping topics, although the underlying functionality (using args) is different.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-02-20**:
Thanks for your help~

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-01**:
This example could be easier to understand if the arg name was 'to_topic'.

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2019-03-19**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1664

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is possible (but not using roslaunch):
rosrun rospy_tutorials talker chatter:=/wg/chatter

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1